# Typescript - Phaser collisions overlap function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, typescript, collision, phaser-framework

So i'm just trying to make a simple collision between falling objects and a players sprite. Its nothing complicated.

I'm trying to use the game.physics.arcade.overlap() function.

Here is my code:

The Player class ->

```
export class Player{
    game: Phaser.Game;
    player: Phaser.Sprite;

    constructor(game:Phaser.Game){
        this.game = game;
        this.player = this.game.add.sprite(400, 520, "Player");
        this.game.physics.arcade.enable(this.player);
    }

    create(){
    }

    update(){

        if (this.game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT))
        {
            if(this.player.x >= -10){
                this.player.x -= 7;
            }
        }
        else if (this.game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT))
        {
            if(this.player.x <= 830){
                this.player.x += 7;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The falling objects class ->

```
    export class Rock {

    game:Phaser.Game;
    rocks: Phaser.Group;

    constructor(game:Phaser.Game){
        this.game = game;
    }

    create(){

        this.rocks = this.game.add.physicsGroup(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        this.game.physics.arcade.enable(this.rocks);

        var x = 10;

        for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            var rock = this.rocks.create(x, this.game.rnd.between(-30,-5), "Rock");
            rock.body.velocity.y = this.game.rnd.between(240,300);
            x += 105;
        }
    }

    update(player){
        this.rocks.forEach(this.checkPos, this);
    }

    checkPos(rock) {
        if (rock.y > 800)
        {
            rock.y = -100;
        }
    }
}
```

The Main Game File where i'm using the overlap function ->

```
 create(){

        this.difficulties = [];
        this.difficulties.push(new Difficulty(0, 5));
        this.difficulties.push(new Difficulty(1, 7));
        this.difficulties.push(new Difficulty(2, 9));
        this.currentDifficulty = this.difficulties[0];
        this.shouldChangeDifficulty = true;

        this.levelOne = new LevelOne(this.game);
        this.levelOne.create(this.currentDifficulty);
        this.currentLevel = this.levelOne;

        this.player = new Player(this.game);
        this.player.create();

        this.rocks = new Rock(this.game);
        this.rocks.create();
    }

    update(){
        this.player.update();
        this.rocks.update(this.player);

        this.game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.player, this.rocks, this.collisionHandler, null, this);
    }

    collisionHandler (player, rock) {
        console.log("Does it work ?!");
    }
```

Comment: I do not know the development of Phaser with TypeScript but I want to ask you something: Do you have any errors from the console? Have you activated physics correctly?:    `this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with several phaser functions in typescript. I was able to get things to work with inline lambda functions.

this.game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.player, this.rocks, (p, r) => {console.log("Does it work?!"); }, null, this);